# Server doesn't detect SIM slot but Desktop does. (18.04 LTS)

Tags: server, interface, wwan

I'm currently working with a **Dell Gateway 5000** and **Ubuntu Server 18**.

When I enter `nmcli device` or `ifconfig`, the SIM interface (WWAN) doesn't appear. It shows other ports, such as wired Ethernet.  Also, it doesn't even show when the enp1s0 interface is connected (although I do have Internet connection).

Don't know if it's necessary to up the interfaces, installing drivers or something else, and if so, How can I do it?

I tested with Ubuntu Desktop and the WWAN appears AOK.

Thanks in advance.